# How i can create a wrapper over ReentrantReadWriteLock ReadLock and WriteLock

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, locks, reentrantreadwritelock

I have a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. The `ReentrantReadWriteLock` contains ReadLock and WriteLock as subclasses.

```
I want to extend this ReadLock and WriteLock by my custom classes as 

DummyReadLock and DummyWriteLock.
```

Then I must be able to do something like below

```
 final Lock lock = new DummyReadLock.readLock();
```

or

```
final Lock lock = new DummyWriteLock.writeLock();
```

Is it possible to achieve this.?

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense to me. If `DummyReadLock` is extending `ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock`, then why does it need a `readLock()` method? I think what you want to do is create a `DummyReadWriteLock` class that extends `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, *as well as* a `DummyReadWriteLock.ReadLock` that extends `ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock` (and similarly for the write-lock). Also, a point of terminology: those are "nested classes", not "subclasses". "Subclasses" refers to classes that extend other classes using inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you can:

```
class DummyReadLock extends ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock {

    private ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock readLock;

    // inherited constructor
    protected DummyRLock(ReentrantReadWriteLock rwlock) {
        super(rwlock);
        this.readLock = rwlock.readLock(); 
    }

    public ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock readLock() {
        return readLock;
    }       
}
```

Comment: How to extend a DummyReentrantReadWriteLock ..?

Comment: I don't understand. You said you wanted to extend the ReadLock inside ReentrantReadWriteLock.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should sort of be possible.  I am not sure exactly why you would want to do this, but the below code would extend the ReadLock, for instance.

```
public class DummyReadLock extends ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock
{
  public DummyReadLock(ReentrantReadWriteLock arg0)
  {
    super(arg0);
  }
}
```

Note that the constructor for the ReadLock requires a ReentrantReadWriteLock as a parameter, so you cannot invoke it exactly as you have shown in your example.